# Async Method throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I'm currently having some problems with a method that throws an exception but I'm not sure why. The exception makes my application crash.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
   at Myapp.AutoProcess.<ToRead>d__36.MoveNext()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(Object state)  
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)   
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext,    ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)  
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback   callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)  
   at   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() 
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I run the method on a separate thread

```
Thread listenerThread = new Thread(() => ToRead());
listenerThread.Start();
```

The method that throws the exception looks like this:

```
private async void ToRead()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (this.toRead.Count != 0)
        {
            string protocol = this.toRead[0];
            string[] temp = protocol.Split(',');
            string message = temp[0];
            string UserName = temp[1];
            Process(message, UserName);
            this.toRead.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}
```

It takes incoming messages from a List and filters out the Username and Message to send it to the Process method. I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Note: The exception occurs about once a day running it on a Windows R2 2008 Server. Therefore I cant really debug it in Visual Studio

Comment: Debug the program. Where does it crash? Find out what was null. Did you do any investigation?

Comment: Why are you threading an `async` method? Make it return a `Task` and then you can `await` it.

Comment: Just as Daniel mentioned your ToRead() is just a another thread.so take a look about async and await little bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're seeing that exception crash your process because you're using an `async void` method.

Instead of using a thread, use a task, as such:

```
private async Task ToReadAsync()

Task listenerTask = Task.Run(() => ToReadAsync());
```

And now you'll be able to nicely retrieve the exception in `listenerTask.Exception`. But it probably won't give you much more detail.

What's probably happening is that your `toRead` variable is set to `null` at some point. The entire concept of the current code is wrong; polling like this is most definitely *not* the way to send data from one thread to another. Check out `BlockingCollection` or something like that for a proper approach.