# Async method throw exception without default proxy web api .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous

I working with some API that need to run with async (an await in body also) but it throw an exception like this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

when I call that api without define `defaultProxy` in WebConfige. But in my solution I cannot define `defaultProxy` because it will interrupt some other process.

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466488/async-method-throws-exception) but cannot find the solution :(

So do we have anyway to run the async method without await like create background thread to run some method like `ReadAsStreamAsync` (just an example).

Comment: Please take a look here :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3956100

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Simple, `Null reference exception` is due to attempt to use a `Null` object to call a method, which will never work. `Async-Await` doesn't create background thread. You can wrap a Synchronous method like `ReadAsStream` in a `Task` like `Task.Run(() => ReadAsStream())`, which will still return `awaitable Task`, but doesn't need `Async` method

Comment: Yes I know it, but the main issue here is the async just run when I have default proxy. Not about the exception at all. Please read my question carefully :|

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Maybe I will go with that way

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy You have highlighted the exception, how carefully shall I read, you need to highlight the main question instead :). 
Nonetheless I have provided you the solution to get that working using simple task API